# Python: os.path.isdir /isfile /exists not working, returning False when they should return True

Tags: python

So, here is my little program. It should print all files in a given directory + all files in every subdirectory.

```
import os

def listFiles(directory):
    dirList = os.listdir(directory)
    printList = []
    for i in dirList:
        i = os.path.join(directory,i)
      #  print(i)
        if os.path.isdir(i):
            printList[len(dirList):] = listFiles(i)
        else:
            printList.append(i)
    return printList

directory = 'C:\Python32\Lib'
listFiles(directory)
a = listFiles(directory)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

What's the problem: os.path.isdir(i) isn't working properly - for example, if I try

```
os.path.isfile('C:\Python32\Lib\concurrent\futures\process.py')
os.path.exists('C:\Python32\Lib\concurrent\futures\process.py')
os.path.isdir('C:\Python32\Lib\concurrent\futures')
```

I always get False instead of True (it works ok for some of the subdirectories). If I uncomment print(i) it prints everything just fine but it also prints directories - I want just to print files. What should I do?

Comment: It works in shell if I use raw string (I put r before string), but how can I make this work inside program/variable?

Comment: You want to use `.extend()` instead of your complicated slice assignment.

Comment: Have you looked into `os.walk()` at all? It'll do all this work for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know about os.walk() but I wanted to do it like I did. Anyway .extend() solves the problem! Thanks.

Comment: For any paths you hardcode, you need to be careful about backslashes.  `\f` is the form-feed character, and is probably not what you intend.  You should either use double backslashes, `C:\\Python32\\...` or use raw strings, `r'C:\Python32\...'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `printList[len(dirList):] = listFiles(i)` is going to overwrite values every loop.

If all your entries in `dirList` are directories, for example, you'll end up with removing entries from `printList` as you loop over each subdir:

```
>>> printList = []
>>> len_dirlist = 2  # make up a size
>>> printList[len_dirlist:] = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] # subdir 1 read
>>> printList
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> printList[len_dirlist:] = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs'] # subdir 2 read
>>> printList
['foo', 'bar', 'spam', 'ham', 'eggs']  # Wait, where did 'baz' go?
```

You want to use `.extend()` instead when adding items to the end of your list.

Note that on Windows, you don't have to use backslashes as path separators, it's better to use forward slashes, as these do not have special meaning in Python strings:

```
'C:/Python32/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py'
```

Alternatively, use `r''` *raw* string literals to remove the chance backslashes are interpreted as character escapes:

```
r'C:\Python32\Lib\concurrent\futures\process.py'
```